# how do you check if a lists exists or not?

Tags: r

I am reading an html table. As a result, sometimes I get one list and sometimes I get two lists.

```
url<-c("example.com/table")
q <- html(url1) %>% html_table(fill=T)
if(exists('q[[2]]')){
```

I need to put in a check that if q[[2]] exists do something, if now just process q[[1]]

I tried exists and

```
if(!is.na(q[[2]]))
```

I get this error on both:

```
Error in q[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

how do you check if lists exists or not?

Comment: Why not just check the length of `q`? Or alternatively that a specific element is not null?

Comment: have you tried `length(q) > 1`

Comment: @joran and chris, that's a good point. thank  you